# Как изображение base64_decode залить в ftp другого хостинга через ftp_put

Tags: php, base64

Добрый день, мне на сервер приходят изображения в кодировке base64, как мне их залить в FTP облако через ftp_put?

Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать это так, но это не работает.

```
$imsrc = base64_decode($_POST['base64']);
$connect = ftp_connect($host);
if(!$connect) die("error connect");
$result = ftp_login($connect, $login, $pass);
if ($result==false) die("error res");
if (ftp_chdir($connect, $path)) {

    if (ftp_put($connect, $aname, $imsrc, FTP_BINARY))
        echo $aname;
    else 
        echo "error";

}
```

Выдает error.

Пробовал еще добавлять

```
$tmp = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fputs($tmp, $imsrc);
rewind($tmp);
...
if (ftp_put($connect, $aname, $tmp, FTP_BINARY))
...
```

И снова error.

Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ftp_put принимает на вход только пути. Не содержимое файла, или file stream. Сохраните содержимое файлом и залейте нормально, после можно удалить.

```
$imsrc = base64_decode($_POST['base64']);
file_put_contents('temporary/'.$aname,$imsrc);

$connect = ftp_connect($host);
if(!$connect) die("error connect");
$result = ftp_login($connect, $login, $pass);
if ($result==false) die("error res");
if (ftp_chdir($connect, $path)) {

    if (ftp_put($connect, $aname, 'temporary/'.$aname, FTP_BINARY))
        echo $aname;
    else 
        echo "error";

}
unlink('temporary/'.$aname);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.